# Serve modules without publishing fails to publish the changes

Tags: tomcat6, myeclipse

I have enabled serve modules directly from workspace on the server overview page. PFB my settings:

[image: server overwiew settings]

So I published the project and restart the server, and it works. I am able to access the index page on the browser.

Now when I make any change to a simple jsp, I see the following in the console:

[image: eclipse console]

I see that it undeployed the web application and a message saying it is deploying the webapplication. But nothing happens after this. This message "deploying webapplication directory mobiledoc" stays forever and nothing happens. If I try to access the index page obviously i get 404. Can somebody please help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this was an issue, but i got a workaround. Leaving it here just in case somebody needs it.

In the publishing settings i selected 'never publish automatically'. Now the changes made to webcontent are reflected at the moment since they are served directly from workspace.